# tools/android returned can\'t find sdkmanager.jar

Tags: php, android, linux

I am trying to use a web server (written in php) to build an android project (the server is Apache.  The php script simply calls proc_open to start 
"/vol1/android_sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update project --target 4 –-name Theme2 --path /vol1/tmp/BuildTest"

android is started, but it returned "android: can\'t find sdkmanager.jar"

I'd tried to work around that by setting:
CLASSPATH=$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools/lib
in the environment, but it didn't change the result.

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: did you get a solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set CLASSPATH? It will have to be where the user running Apache can access it.  You might have to make sure the user ENV variable is accessible by using mod_env and SetEnv to gain access.